# javascript convert to turkish character fromCharCode

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, char, turkish, fromcharcode

I print the value entered from the keyboard to the screen. but Turkish characters are written to the screen in a distorted way. How can I print Turkish characters properly?

my javascript codes:

```
window.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){

    var span = this.document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    span.style.color='white';
    var harfDivleri = this.document.querySelectorAll('.harfDivleri');

    var i = kelimeDiv.children.length;
    while (0 < i) {
        i--;
         if(harfDivleri[i].innerHTML == ""){
            harfDivleri[i].appendChild(span);
        }
    }
    
});
```

screen output:

[image]

I want to be able to write such characters: ÖÜĞİŞÇ

Comment: Did you try `fromCodePoint` instead of `fromCharCode`? Also, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) for some related issues (for one it seems you'd probably be better off using the `keypress` event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `keypress` event, this will give you the actual character code as opposed to the physical key clicked, this is explained in more detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)

The keydown and keyup events provide a code indicating which *key* is pressed, while keypress indicates which *character* was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events.

If you use the keypress event, your code should work as expected, see the simple demo below, Turkish characters should be rendered correctly.

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
})
```

```html
<h3>Type here to see text:</h3><br>

<h3 id='output'></h3>
```

Comment: thanks. I did with yesterday different a path. But this too works